# application/json versus application/x-www-form-urlencoded for POST request

Tags: json, post, encoding

I want to send JSON data (stringified) in an ajax POST request. How should I think about using `application/json` versus using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (along with `encodeURIComponent`)?